# What am I doing wrong to get an 500 statusCode

Tags: socrata, soda

Is this code supported by [soda-js](https://github.com/socrata/soda-js), and if so, why am I getting a 500 status code

```
var identifier = 'fgzt-sd3n'
var op = new soda.Consumer('data.cms.gov', options);
op.query()
    .withDataset(identifier)
    .where({npi:"in('1598908824','1194758300')"})
    .getRows()
    .on('success', function(rows){console.log(rows)})
    .on('error', function(error){console.log(error)})
}
```

Also can my list be an array or atleast a string variable maybe like

```
'in('+strList+')'
```

where

```
var strList="'1598908824','1194758300'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var identifier = 'fgzt-sd3n' var op = new
soda.Consumer('data.cms.gov', options); op.query()
    .withDataset(identifier)
    .where({"npi in('1598908824','1194758300')"})
    .getRows()
    .on('success', function(rows){console.log(rows)})
    .on('error', function(error){console.log(error)}) }
```

I suspect that the `where` you were passing before got you a SoQL query of `$where=npi=in(...)` which would fail.

You should have received a `400` error instead of an unhelpful `500` - I'll file a bug on that one!

Comment: Ok, I think you meant `where("npi in('1598908824','1194758300')")` which works perfect.  Thanks

Comment: what is the limit on elements i can have within the `in(...)`.  500 elements is clearly not supported as it returns `{}`

Comment: It depends on your HTTP library, but your total SoQL query length needs to be less than 2000 to 4000 characters. Our system will block anything longer than about 4000, but many library implementations cap out closer to 2000.